# How can I convert <br> string into actual HTML <br> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Maybe the question is phrased incorrectly, but here is what I'm trying to do with jQuery:

**Starting Point:**

```
This is<br><br> some<br> <br> <br> <br> content
```

**End Goal:**

```
This is

some



content
```

**Explanation:**

More specifically, I'm having issues working with content in a div, which then turns into a textarea on edit and then back to a div when done editing.  The database has to store the < br > tags on save... it seems that textareas use newlines (\n) and returns (\r) instead so the conversion between these (< br >, \n and \r) is becoming a bit of an issue for me.

Is there a proper way to handle this between multiple browsers?  Perhaps it might be easier to just use textarea's the whole time (and forget about the divs)?  It's when I try to move the content between a div and a textarea and then back to a div, funky things start to happen with the spacing.

**More Detail Edit:**

If the user clicks edit and turns the original div into a textarea, they start making changes and click done, but decide to cancel editing and revert to the old content instead. The textarea turns back into a div and the old content (stored in a hidden div) replaces what the user had written. Hence the back and forth of content.

**Edit:**

Great feedback, thanks all!  I'd prefer not to use the whtiespace css as this needs to work on websites that have been developed already and would require edits on all of the divs holding the content on every page.  < br >'s must be saved in the database.

Comment: You pointed out the problem ! The text-area uses \r as line break. HTML uses <br>

Comment: Have you tried something like `.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")`?

Comment: You can use `white-space:pre-line;` on the div and not worry about storing it as `<br/>`. ;-)

Comment: Would using [Markdown](http://epiceditor.com/) be an option?

Comment: Here's an example of what @BradChristie is describing: http://jsfiddle.net/C8Fnz/

Comment: @BradChristie you should post that as an answer

Comment: The example of @BradChristie does'nt work if you copy text from the div to the textarea. Line breaks are broken !!!

Comment: Incase you are using php, php has [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) function whose js equivalent is [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br/).

Comment: @TCHdvlp I wouldn't expect it to

Comment: @TCHdvlp: That wasn't one of the requirements. They're using a textbox for edit mode and a div for display mode. The user's never expected to copy from one to the other. And the `white-space` style works great without making every new-line 4 bytes long.

Comment: @billyonecan, `"It's when I try to move the content between a div and a textarea and then back to a div"` This sentence had let me think it was requirement...

Comment: This is correct, if the user clicks edit and turns the original div into a textarea, they start making changes and click done, but decide to cancel editing and revert instead, the textarea turns back into a div and the old content (stored in a hidden div) replaces what the user had written.  Hence the back and forth of content.

Comment: @TCHdvlp I thought about using textarea's only but the problem with that now becomes the height of the content.  I've tried to use autosize plugins on textareas but they always seems to add extra height beyond the content.

Comment: Maybe you should consider Brad Christie's and billyonecan's comments as parts of a complete solution. Each time a user want to edit a div, use ajax to load original text from database. Load it into a textarea. If user cancels the action, just get rid of the textarea and display your div as it was. If he confirms the changes. Use ajax to save edited text and put it into the div with the `whitespace` solution. You will have a clean and constent solution. So you will have to forget about moving data from a div to a textarea. It will allways be : `database->div` or `database->textarea->div`.

Comment: @tchdclp I implied coder not visitor from my perspective.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this help?

```
function replaceLineBreaksWithHTML(string) {
 return string !== undefined ? string.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') : "";
}

function replaceHTMLWithLineBreaks(string) {
 return string !== undefined ? string.replace(/<br\/>/gi, '\n') : "";
}
```

Comment: This seems to have the effect I want, but adds more extra space than is required.  For some reason, most of these answers add more space. Almost as if it's doubling up on white space.

Comment: My solution isn't adding any whitespace, it may be that there is whitespace you're not thinking about beforehand. You can try calling .trim() on strings to remove whitespace at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the text between `textarea` and `div` elements this way:

(note that I am using jQuery but it is not necessary, it is just a demo)

```
$("#b1").click(function(){
    var text = $("textarea").val().replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
    $("div").html(text);
});

$("#b2").click(function(){
    var text = $("div").html().replace(/<br>/gi, "\n");
    $("textarea").val(text);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/378TJ/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace regex to convert br to \n :)

```
$('#mytextarea').val($.trim($('#mydiv').html().replace(/<br>/g, '\n')));
```

Just have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N7GkH/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) for this job, given that you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
var html = $.parseHTML('This is<br><br> some<br> <br> <br> <br> content');
html.appendTo(body);
```